# Facebook posting status containing html

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I am posting status using Facebook C# SDK. It works fine but I when my post contains some html it doesn't work. Basically it contains anchor tag and my site's link.

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isnt an error, this is intended. You cant send HTML in a post status, regular URL's will be parsed as anchor tags though.

Comment: Infact when I post on facebook directly then also it doesn't work. This is the url: http://localhost:9000/RecruiterProfile/JobView/0. Can localhost be the culprit here?

Comment: Well posting a link to localhost obviously wouldnt be of much use to anyone else but you. Perhaps Facebook doesnt recognise it as an URL, because there is no `http`, `www` nor any tld (.com, .co.uk etc)